# Delphi Lock the size of form

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-7

I've loaded a very nice image as background in my program, the problem is that there is part of the program that is white, because the image does not cover all the background. I can set the exe's size, but users can change the size, which is something i don't want to. How am i doing it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The form's BorderStyle determines whether the user can resize the form or not.  Set the BorderStyle to a non-sizable value (bsDialog, bsSingle or bsNone), and then set the form's ClientWidth/ClientHeight to the desired values to match your background image.